# Android Heap Size

Tags: android, memory-management, android-memory

I Am developing a game with *eclipse*, the problem is android **heap size** in my game is about 24-25MB.
and the reason is the images I Show into my `Activitys`.
But in another Apps like *Instagram*, Or games made by *Unity Engine*, Even though There are a lots of images on the app, **heap size** is around 4-5MB.

I have scaled my pictures Down As I could, 
What Can I Do to Load the `imageView` Resources Not into **Heap**? Is it possible?

How About `ImageButtons`? Should I take care Of them Same As `ImageViews`?

Comment: Why do you think there is any problem at all? Do you have any actual problems? Maybe an `OutOfMemoryExveption? If your app works then it can be completely normal that it uses that much memory.

Comment: Also 25MB really isn't that much. If you are asking just because it uses that amount of memory than there is nothing wrong at all.

Comment: And where else are your images supposed to go other than heap memory? That's what it is for, there is nothing else.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Yes, In some devices the App gets OutOfMemory Error.

Comment: Then add the stack traces. Show us some code. Nobody can help you if you don't show us the exceptions and what you are doing.